# Selectize - Create & Options don't work together

Tags: jquery, selectize.js

I am able to get both of these to work separately but when I try to have both features in one initiation that doesn't work.

**Only Create**

```
$('#input-tags').selectize({
     delimiter: ',',
     persist: false,
     create: function(input) {
        return {
           value: input,
           text: input
        }
     }
});
```

**Both Create & Options**

```
var data = [ "option 1", "option 2", "option 3" ];
var items = data.map(function(x) { return { item: x }; });

$('#input-tags').selectize({
    delimiter: ',',
    persist: false,
    maxItems: 2,
    options: items,
    labelField: "item",
    valueField: "item",
    sortField: 'item',
    searchField: 'item',
    create: function(input) {
        return {
            value: input,
            text: input
        }
    }
});
```

In second one, when you click on "Add text" it doesn't show as a tag in the input field. And click on anywhere else on the screen makes it disappear.

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/2ZrEu/

Answer (score 5):

In the combined example you set labelField & valueField to 'item'.
So your create function has to return a item field.

```
create: function(input) {
        return {
            item: input
        }
    }
```

Comment: This just solved my problem after a lot of time... it's not documented very clearly?

Comment: Can not realy remember, as we have moved on from selectize as we changed to Angular.
The documentation of selectize is not that bad but sometimes it helped to look directly into the sourcecode i think.